# Uploading Data in Background (iOS & Android) fails in a strange way after a while

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am working to evolve the App we use for our boating community. Part of it is a map on a website with recent location from Boats. Everything works so far, but I want to add a continous background tracking as an App-Feature.

The App works for a while but than fails uploading due to timeouts. These do not come from API limitations and to me it looks like the App just cant access the network anymore.

I depend on https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin for all Location-Things. The Plugin also uses https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin/ on Android.

So, here is what I do after I receive a location update from the phone.

Event Handler Setup:

```
[...]
            TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan(0, 20, 0);  // Prod: 0, 30,  0
            double distance = 500;   // Prod: 2700

            bool includeHeading = false; //don't alert on heading changes 

            ListenerSettings listenerSettings = new ListenerSettings
            {
                AllowBackgroundUpdates = true,
                DeferralDistanceMeters = distance,      // adjustable in app 2-10 nautical Miles
                DeferLocationUpdates = true,
                DeferralTime = span,                    // adjustable in app 15-120 Minutes
                ListenForSignificantChanges = false,
                PauseLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false,
                ActivityType = ActivityType.OtherNavigation
            };

            var success = await CrossGeolocator.Current.StartListeningAsync(span,distance,includeHeading,listenerSettings);

            if (success)
            {
                CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionChanged += async (s, e) =>
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("\n\n -_-_-_-_-_ Position Event -_-_-_-_-_-_ \n\n");
                    Trackpoint trackpoint = new Trackpoint(e.Position);
                    Trackpoint point = await Tracking(trackpoint);
                };
            }
[...]
```

The Event Handler calls: (more stuff will happen there further down the app's development roadmap)

```
public async Task<Trackpoint> Tracking(Trackpoint trackpoint = null)
        {
            return await tracker.LogPoint(trackpoint);
        }
```

In `tracker.LogPoint(trackpoint)` the coordinate from Hevent Handler is added to a List (that should be empty but may hold previous Trackpoints in case uploads failed.)

```
public async Task<Trackpoint> LogPoint(Trackpoint location = null)
        {
            if (location == null)
            {
                location = await GetCoordinates();   // Call GPS if no Trackpoint is given when Tracking is done fully manual
            }

            if (location != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Trackpoint Queue was: {0}", track.Count);
                track.Add(location);   // Add current location to end of the list (defined as private in the class)
                int trackpointQueue = track.Count;
                int uploadedTrackpoints = 0;

                Console.WriteLine("Trackpoint Queue now: {0}", trackpointQueue);

                foreach (var position in track)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Uploading Trackpoint: {0} | {1} | {2}", position.Timestamp, position.Latitude, position.Longitude);
                    if (App.api.UploadTrackPoint(track[track.Count - 1]))   // upload first trackpoint in List (ideally current) and remove it from List, repeat with more items in queue.
                    {
                        uploadedTrackpoints++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error uploading Trackpoint trying again next time");
                        // Because uploading attempt failed, we don't want to try again now leave the loop until next call.
                        break;
                    }
                }
                track.RemoveRange(0, uploadedTrackpoints); // remove all uploaded Trackpoints from Queue
            }
            return location;
        }
```

The Upload happens as multipart/formdata to an existing API. After 4-10 events all further Uploads fail, raising an Exeption because a network timeout occures.
Bringing the App back to foreground it has become almost unresponsive.

```
public bool UploadTrackPoint(Trackpoint location)
        {
            bool success = false;
            if (CanUseData())
            {
                string posturl = settings.BlogURL + "(THE API URL)" + "(THE API KEY)";
                string agent = "User-Agent: (MY APP NAME)/" + settings.Version + " (" + DeviceInfo.Platform + ", " + DeviceInfo.VersionString + ")";

                Console.WriteLine("Uploading: {0} ", Trackpoint.ConvertToString(location));
                try
                {
                    var response = MessageUpload.MultipartFormDataPost(false, posturl, agent, location.Pairs);

                    Console.WriteLine("HTTP response StatusCode: " + response.StatusCode + "\n Content: " + response.ResponseUri);

                    if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK) success = true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("FAILED!!! \n\n({0})\n\n", ex);

                }
            }
            return success;
        }
```

The exact same behaviour happens on iOS (physical iPhone 6) and iOS Simulators and also in Android Simulator.
However I read alot about background limitations on iOS and recent Android APIs but I doubt that this is the issue here because its consitent on both Plattforms. 
So I assume I am doing something wrong here, filling some sort buffer before hitting the wall. 
However, the app is not terminated by any OS while I can see some `-_-_-_-_-_ Position Event -_-_-_-_-_-_` on the Console after the uploading starts to fail and the backlog is growing. 
Eventually after some timeouts happen even the location updates stop.

Where would you start further debugging?

Comment: Can you show the actual http client calls?

Comment: You will have to implement native code within each of the platforms. On Android, you will have to implement a "foregrounded" Service (at a minimum) and on iOS you will have to entitle it for background updates and enable a CLLocationManager instance for background updates. Xamarin has docs (and an aging demo) for just this: https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/mobile/BackgroundLocationDemo/ (Note: be sure to review the platform based links in that link)

Comment: @SushiHangover Thnks for looking into this. I may be wrong but from my understanding that is exactly what JamesMontemagno is covering with the 2nd Plugin for Android and I do see the Location Events arriving on the console. iOS Permissions are set up.

Comment: @Stefan They are regular multpart/form-data Posts: I will update the post with an example

Comment: @HinnerkWeiler Which plugin? `CurrentActivityPlugin` provides a simple reference to an android activity and his `GeolocatorPlugin` does not implement background/foregrounded services... Unless you are talking about a 3rd plugin that you have not listed, or the actual foregrounded service code that you have written...

Comment: @SushiHangover Sorry for the delay. I have to admit, I misunderstood the purpose of `CurrentActivityPlugin`. But I wonder if that alone will fix the issue since I have the same issue on iOS. From my understanding there is nothing more needed on iOS. I do have ```<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
 <string>[...]</string><key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
 <string>[...]</string>
 <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
 <array>
  <string>location</string>
 </array>```  in `info.plist`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone stumbles upon this. Besides the missing Backgrounnd Service mentioned  by @SushiHangover the bigger issue was an incorrect processing of the WebResponse.

Turns out the gut feeling of hitting some kind of wall was right here: Only reading the headers and never disposing the Response Object after my Http Calls were done the App kept all connections open. After exact 10 (on iOS) the App was not able to open new connections causing the timeouts.